# Anonymous function in obtrusive javascript - browser dependency?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

Am using Salesforce and I need to use stuff like onfocus="js_fn1(this,'param1'..) etc.

For a peculiar requirement, am trying to pass an anonymous function as a parameter to a function I am binding onfocus. Here's the generated HTML:

```
<input onfocus="self=this;new AutoComplete('thePage:j_id3:thePageBlockId:j_id45:j_id46:pName','thePage:j_id3:thePageBlockId:j_id45:j_id46:primaryNameSuggestWrap', searchNamesfn, function(){fireAddressSearch(self, 'thePage:j_id3:thePageBlockId:j_id45:j_id46:address', 'thePage:j_id3:thePageBlockId:j_id45:j_id46:addressSuggestWrap', searchAddressesfn, selectAddressesfn);});return false;" onkeypress="return noenter(event)" id="thePage:j_id3:thePageBlockId:j_id45:j_id46:pName" type="text" name="thePage:j_id3:thePageBlockId:j_id45:j_id46:pName" value="" class="cField" />
```

This works beautifully in Chrome 10 and Firefox 3.6. But it seems to fail in, you guessed it, IE8. I've had a few pokes around this but couldn't conclude anything else - that IE doesn't support anon functions in obtrusive js? IE8 said

```
Message: Not implemented

Line: 219
Char: 1
Code: 0
```

At line 219 I have the input field Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: It seems obvious IE doesn't like your super-long `onfocus` attribute. Why not try and create a handler for it in javascript?

Comment: `self` is a reserved word in JavaScript/JScript. Is IE8 taking exception to you using it?

Comment: `self` is reserved? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @NeXXeuS I can either define the whole thing as a function inside <head/>. But, in the Salesforce page I use `$Component` which is what generates the long strings starting with 'thePage..'. I can't use these things as its parsed before the respective values are available.

I can insert a <script/> tag in the middle to define a function, but I don't really like <script/>s inside <body/>

@meouw,ThiefMaster I don't think self is reserved. Does the message above look like an exception?

Comment: @meouw damn, I did seem to be self!

Comment: this code is not really unobtrusive JS, is it? It violates the very core, separation of markup and programmable logic.

Comment: that's why the question says obtrusive and not unobtrusive :)

Comment: Oh, I was actually looking at tags, you tagged it as unobtrusive. No problem, I'll just remove that tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [meouw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12161/meouw) for the useful comment.

Answer: It seems 'self' is reserved in IE